# Adjust keyboard repeat rate in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard

I'm making the switch from [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) to [XMonad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmonad), and one of the customizations I have made in GNOME which does not translate over to XMonad is an increased keyboard repeat rate. Is there a more general-purpose tool to set the keyboard repeat rate in Linux than something that is dependent upon your desktop environment such as GNOME or [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`xset`**:

```
...
To turn auto-repeat off or on:
    -r [keycode]        r off
     r [keycode]        r on
     r rate [delay [rate]]
...
```

---

Alternatively, run `gnome-settings-daemon` inside xmonad.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I used xset r rate 250 50.